# Time range to index in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetimeindex

For each datapoint (in this example a and b), its specific occurrence time frame is specified:

```
pd.DataFrame([
    {'from': pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'), 'to': pd.Timestamp('2020-01-05')}, 
    {'from': pd.Timestamp('2020-01-02'), 'to': pd.Timestamp('2020-01-03')}
], index=['a', 'b'])
```

I would like to count, for example, when the data point is active over time:

```
2020-01-01    1
2020-01-02    2
2020-01-03    2
2020-01-04    1
2020-01-05    1
```

Is there any convenient way to merge a period (timeframe) to a `DateTimeIndex`, for convenient plotting or counting?

Comment: Yes, of course! Thanks for pointing out. Sorry, my bad. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
from itertools import chain
pd.Series(chain(*[pd.date_range(i, j, freq='D') for i,j in zip(df['from'], df['to'])]))\
  .value_counts().sort_index().plot()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Oh, there is also another nice way using [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), isn't it?

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['from'], x['to'], freq='D'), axis=1).explode()
```